# Why does openSL not report when microphone is in use??? (Android 4.4)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, opensl

This is from logcat:

```
W/AudioPolicyManagerALSA(  169): startInput() input 152 failed: other input already started..
E/AudioRecord(10665): start() status -38

I/myAPP(10665): [myAPP] Opening the microphone went fine...
```

Here is an interop issue between my application and "Hi-Q MP3 Recorder" (from the Android Store). The recorder is recording mic audio in the background and I start my application to record mic audio.

AudioPolicyManagerALSA tells me that the mic is in use, but the message does not propagate up to openSL via AudioRecord (as it SHOULD, right?). As you can see AudioRecord is ALSO aware of the mic being in use! But openSL doesn't tell me anything!

How do you detect if the mic is in use when you're using the openSL audio API ?

Is this a known bug?

Comment: For others who have been through the same headache: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/nOsC8mdNRSg

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65302

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a known issue:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/nOsC8mdNRSg

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65302